# How to change menu item text color programmatically in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:title="@string/action_save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_save"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_menu_save"/>
</menu>
```

This is my function code

```
  fun isAdvanceSearchButtonEnabled(bool: Boolean) {

        menu?.getItem(0)?.setEnabled(bool)

        (menu?.getItem(0) as TextView).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"))

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        inflater?.inflate(R.menu.menu_cs_search_advance, menu)
        this.menu = menu
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.action_advance_search_query -> {

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```

I want to change Menu item color on based of condition but I am not able to get I will case menu item as textview or how to change menu item text color I tried as type cast but it show null can not cast as text view please suggest me how I will change menu item text color problematically in Android

Comment: But icons do not have text.

Comment: i dont have icon its only text can u please tell me how change text color @meditat

Comment: you should check at debug what instance is null, maybe menu doesn't get initialized and it's null all the way

Comment: you want to change text color of menu with xml or kotlin?

Comment: yes yes @willywijaya

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change MenuItem text color programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713628/change-menuitem-text-color-programmatically)

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot i tried this but not able to to achieve problematically based on condition